# am I using "that" in the correct way please?

Tags: sentence-construction, subordinate-clauses, grammaticality-in-context

I am writing to my manager. I want to suggest to her making a new service.
I have problem with this sentence

> Can you suggest to them that `Company Name` develops the Italian version of the website?

Am I using *that* correctly in this context please?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence

> Can you suggest to them *that* Company Name develops the Italian version of the website?

uses *that* in a correct way.

However, if there is no Italian version of the website present at the moment, I would put it thus:

> Can you suggest to them that Company Name develops *an* Italian version of the website?

with the indefinite article making clear that the task is not to work on an existing Italian version but to create one from the scratch. I could be wrong here, I do make mistakes in article usage sometimes, so look out for comments to my answer.

And another niggle: it might be more proper to write

> Can you suggest to them that Company Name **develop** an Italian version of the website?

When someone suggests to another person to do something (yet undone; hypothetically), the sentence often assumes the "[subjunctive mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood)", and there is a quaint rule that the verb should be put in the infinitive form despite it being in the third person singular:

> "I suggest that Paul **eat** an apple"

(not **eats** an apple)

Comment: The choice of articles is more subtle than just whether the site exists yet or not. If there's going to be one and only one Italian website, using "the" is still correct, but you might use "an" the first time you introduce it, or if it's uncertain whether there will be one or not. Hence, "We're going to create an Italian version of the website", "So you think we really need an Italian version?". Then, once you've decided to do it but before work starts, "Who shall we get to create the Italian version of the website?". It will exist (as far as we expect, anyway).

Comment: ... my observation as a speaker (not an academic or a grammar expert) is that the longer you talk about *a* hypothetical future thing, the more likely it is to transform into *the* future thing.

Answer (score 0):

If it is clear who "them" refers to, you can also leave it out:

> Can you suggest that Company Name develop....

Comment: Well, yes, you can leave it out, but you never need to know the referent.

Comment: The question asks if the word _that_ is being used correctly in this phrase. This user has explained another way the word _that_ can be used in this phrase. I think this information could be helpful to the learner. Please do not flag this answer.